# Selenium Webdriver Sendkeys

Tags: selenium

I used the below code to input the

```
username.WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("userid")).sendKeys("happytesting");
```

It shows red line below the sendKeys. Please help to resolve.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a community for the programmers by the programmers, please visit its [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section before posting any question, as it will help you as well as other SOusers too.

Answer (score 0):

1) I am assuming `username` in `username.WebElement()` defined and
    initialized something like this:

```
WebDriver username=new FirefoxDriver();
```

Otherwise there is no way to do `*.WebElement`. Still you need add typecasting something like this:

```
username.WebElement userName = (username.WebElement)
username.findElement(By.id("userid"));
((WebElement) username).sendKeys("happytesting");
```

2) Otherwise there is some wrong understanding. You can simplify your
    code and remove that ***red line*** by using:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement username= driver.findElement(By.id("userid"));
username.sendKeys("happytesting");
```